# Add empty table rows to a Table until it has a certain number of rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

There is a table and it must have a fixed number of rows, let's say 10. If there are less than 10 rows with data, it must be added "empty" rows until there are 10.

So far the code adds one row if there are less than 10:

```
  import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';

  ...

  {rows.length < 10 ? (
    <Table.Row
      className="disabled-row">
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  ) : (
    ''
  )}
```

Is there a way to use something like a `forEach()` or `while()` that adds a new row for each iteration between `row.length` and `10`?

If that is possible it could be used also for table cells, instead of writing 8 identical cells to write a function for that.

Comment: You could create an array that contains as many elements as rows need to be created (e.g. `new Array(10 - rows.length)`) and `map()` over that array outputting the `<Table.Row>...</Table.Row>` components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print rows dynamically like this:

```
<Table.Row className="disabled-row">
          
  {
    [...Array(10 - row.length)].map((e, i) => <Table.Cell id="cta" 
    textAlign="right"></Table.Cell>
  }

</Table.Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map over the rows if rows length less than 10. Try this out. Hope it will work.

```
{rows.length < 10 && (
  <Table.Row className="disabled-row">
    {rows.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Table.Cell id="cta" textAlign="right" key={index}>
          {item}
        </Table.Cell>
      );
    })}
 </Table.Row>   
)}
```

Comment: when does it know to stop?